# Export certificates from java?

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate, truststore

We had some https certificates installed under java 5 keystore.
I am looking forward to migrate my old ssl certificate from java 5 trustore to java 6 trustore or is it a good option to replace java 6 kdystore file wuth java 5 keystore file(though i wont prefer this)?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have done that in the first place. If you have additional certificates you want to trust you should pay them in your own cacerts file. If you need the JRE ones as well, have a build step that imports those into your file.

Comment: The best solution is still what I suggested above. Not sure why you're expecting me to say anything different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

- `keytool -list` to find the alias of the certificate you want to migrate,
- [`keytool -export -alias ...`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step5.html) to export it into a file,
- `keytool -import ...` to import it into the new trust store. (The default password is `changeit`, except on some versions of OSX where it's `changeme`).

Comment: I suppose you could write a script that merges both, but that would defeat the point of having an updated trust store: it would also re-import other CA certificates that may have been removed on purpose (e.g. because of security breaches at the CA). It's not a bad thing to have to know which CA certificate of yours you want to re-import.